# Change workflow transition state of translated node

Tags: 8, workflows

I have a content node that has several translated nodes attached to it. My goal is to set the workflow transition state of translated nodes according to the state of the "original" node.

The problem is, that the "original" node properly changes its workflow transition state, but the translated nodes are untouched.

My code so far (called in a form_submit handler):

```
$entity= \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
$user = User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
$formToState = $form_state->getValue('field_workflow_state')[0]['workflow_transition']->getToState()->id();
$existingTranslations = array_keys($entity->getTranslationLanguages());
$currentLanguage = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
$fieldName = 'field_workflow_state';
foreach ($existingTranslations as $translationAbbreviation) {
  if ($currentLanguage !== $translationAbbreviation) {
    $translatedEntity = $entity->getTranslation($translationAbbreviation);
    $currentSid = $translatedEntity->$fieldName->value;
    $transition = WorkflowTransition::create([$currentSid, 'field_name' => $fieldName]);
    $transition->setTargetEntity($translatedEntity);
    $comment = $form['field_workflow_state']['widget'][0]['comment']['#value'];
    $transition->setValues($formToState, $user->id(), \Drupal::time()->getRequestTime(), $comment, true);
    $transitionId = $transition->execute(true);
    $translatedEntity->$fieldName->value = $transitionId;
    $translatedEntity->save();
  }
}
```

The transitions seem to be executed correctly, but if I check, they are still in the old state. 
Can someone point me to where the problem is?

Edit: I noticed, that I get several Warnings 'Transition is executed twice in a call. The second call for node 1 is not executed.' when trying to update the workflow state of all of the nodes translations. That could explain that the state of the translations doesn't update. But how can the workflow state of the translations be synced to the main (in this case english) one?

Comment: where you put your code? Node form alter, form transition ... ?

Comment: "(called in a form_submit handler)"

Comment: Why are you loading the node entity from the request and not from the $form_state?

Comment: e.g.  `$entity = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();`

Comment: do you want change state of workflow ?

Comment: @vinhdv yes, as described in the question

Comment: @StefanosPetrakis no real reason. Is there a difference?

Comment: Shouldn't play a part in your current situation @plocks ; it's just better to rely on the actual form state instead of picking entities from the route.

Comment: @StefanosPetrakis OK, thanks for the tipp though.

Comment: As of your code, your using workflow (contrib module). Are you sure that not workflows (core module) is in place ?

Comment: Yes, I am using the contrib workflow module. What exactly do you mean by "in place"? Putting the node into the next step works without problems indeed, even with my provided code. But trying to advance the translations of that node to the same state, doesn't work and instead logs the warning about the double execution of the transition. I think it is a bug in the workflow contrib module, because it thinks it advances the same node all the time, instead of checking if the node, which naturally has the same ID than the "original", is a translated node and advance it.

Comment: By in place I meant "active". This module in core just made it in in a recent release ..

Comment: Ok yeah, the contrib module is the active one.